# Custom backButtonIcon for NavigatorIOS

Tags: react-native

This question is related to

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1383

Is there anyway to have a custom back button icon / title with NavigatorIOS?

`backButtonIcon, backButtonTitle` is not working as expected. The left arrow is always visible. New routes with custom backButtonIcon or backButtonTitle doesnt show

`this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'Next',
    component: Next,
    backButtonIcon: require('./../img/Back.png')

})`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use LeftButtonIcon instead of backButtonIcon like this;

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: '详情',
    component: PageList,
    leftButtonIcon: {uri: 'nav-back'},
    onLeftButtonPress: () => {
      ViewController.toggleTabBar(true);
      this.props.navigator.pop();
    },
    passProps: {
      data: data
    }
  });
```

The letButtonIcon comes from Native App.

Comment: `Swipe to go back` is lost when using custom left button

Comment: @vinay That's TRUE. Do u have a solution for it?

Comment: Nope. I am using JS Navigator instead

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using the Navigator component. Navigator is the JS implementation of a navigator. You can customize every aspect of it and you can use it in both iOS and Android. Further more, NavigatorIos is not maintained as much as Navigator. More info here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator-comparison.html#content

And here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content

Comment: Yes. But i am looking to achieve this with NavigatorIOS. If anyone has done it, please share